# How to set DLLImport's dll name?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a library name that depends upon other conditions.  Essentially, NATIVELIBRARY needs to be a parameter:

```
// Logic to set NATIVELIBRARY

[DllImport(NATIVELIBRARY,...)]
public static extern....
```

Comment: So, you need to pragmatically get that name before you do the import?

Comment: yes.  the name depends on other stuff.

Comment: Is this for pInvoke stuff?

Comment: How many different cases do you have? If it's a small number, then you could hard code multiple DllImport's. If not you could use one of these solutions similar to this stackoverflow.com/a/8836228/161455.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. .NET interop is not exactly a super full features thing an you are out of recommended standard behavior.

This is the moment where C++/CLR comes in handy, where you can write a managed class on one side, and have total freedom to do what you want (including dynamically loading dll's) on the other side.

Comment: unfortunately, this is on linux.